# Sorting Logic - Clarifiaciton

Tags: sorting, sas, proc

I have a doubt about sorting logic. For explanation, I am providing a scenario here

I have 3 datasets and want to remove duplicate between the datasets and the final result should NOT be a single combined dataset , instead the result datasets should be seperate but without duplicates. like

TEST1 , TEST2, TEST3. Each of the dataset contains duplicates. After removing duplicates, still the datasets should be TEST1, TEST2, TEST3, but without any duplicates between the 3 datasets

**Logic Used:**

```
data
enter code herefinal;
 set test1 test2 test3 indsname=dsn;
 memnm=dsn;
run;

proc sort data=final nodupkey; by var var2; run;

data
 test1 test2 test3;
set
 final;
if memnm = 'test1' then output test1;
if memnm = 'test2' then output test2;
if memnm = 'test3' then output test3;
run;
```

I want to know whether the order of the rows of the datasets(test1,2,3) will be still preserved in the final dataset and even after the sorting procedure completion. Like as I am ordering the datasets while setting them in final dataset, will that order be changed during the sort procedure, or NOT
**Note: The order of datasets(test1,2,3) will NOT be changed in the SET statement**

Please provide a suggestion on this.

As far as I have tested this code, I have not seen any order change. But really want to confirm on it. If someone has any idea or document related to the ordering logic of sort step, it will be very helpful

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The sort procedure will sort the rows in `final` by `var` and `var2` and therefore your result datasets `test1`,`test2` and `test3` will also each be sorted by `var` and `var2`. If you want to preserve the order of your `test` datasets as it was before your program, you could for instance store the `_N_` variable in your `final` dataset and sort on it after splitting your data based on `memnm`.

Though if your datasets contain other variables that `var` and `var2`, be aware that you are removing duplicate **keys** (var,var2), not duplicate **records**. `proc sort nodupkey` will keep the first record it encounters with a specific key in the order that they appear in final and discard the other regardless of the values variables other than `var` and `var2`.
For instance if you had test1:

```
var  var2  var3
---------------
one  two   foo
```

and test2:

```
var  var2  var3
---------------
one  two   bar
```

After your `proc sort`, you would have table `final`:

```
var  var2  var3
---------------
one  two   foo
```

and the `bar` record would be gone.
To remove duplicate records you can use option `noduprec` instead of `nodupkey`

Answer (score 0):

PROC SORT will preserve the relative order of observations within the BY groups.

If you want to combine three datasets that are already sorted then you can use the BY statement in combination with the SET statement.  So if you wanted to combine three datasets and keep the first observation found in each BY group and also record which dataset contributed that observation you could use code like this.

```
data final ;
  set test1 test2 test3 indsname=dsn;
  by var var2;
  if first.var2; 
  memnm=dsn;
run;
```